# Why is this for loop not looping more than once?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm currently still learning java so this is probably just an amateur mistake

The intention was that the 'for' loop would draw out an array of 'Bars' onto a bar chart given different heights (apologies for the poor formatting)

```
static int[]cwMarks = new int[4];
static int[]examMarks = new int[4];
static int barWidth = 4; //Standard bar width
private static int posX = -15; //Decides X position of bar
private static int posY= 210; //Decides Y position of bar
static int barCount = 8; //Tracks number of bars needing to be drawn
static Bar[] barArr = new Bar[barCount]; //Array storing Bars

    cwMarks[0]=50;
    cwMarks[1]=100;
    cwMarks[2]=20;
    cwMarks[3]=100;
    examMarks[0]=50;
    examMarks[1]=100;
    examMarks[2]= 20;
    examMarks[3]= 30;
    draw();

public static void draw()
{

    for (int i=0,j=0;i<barCount;j++) //i represents the element of barArr, j represents element of cwMarks/examMarks
    {


        barArr[i].moveHorizontal(posX);
        barArr[i].changeSize(barWidth, cwMarks[j]);
        barArr[i].moveVertical(posY-cwMarks[j]);
        barArr[i].makeVisible();
        i++;

        barArr[i].moveHorizontal(posX+barWidth+1);
        barArr[i].changeSize(barWidth, examMarks[j]);
        barArr[i].moveVertical(posY-examMarks[j]);
        barArr[i].makeVisible();
        i++;

        posX=+5;

    }

}

`
```

I assumed that this would created 4 pairs of 2 bars, but instead the loop only seems to execute it's code twice (producing 2 pairs of 2). This is what is drawn:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: Are you sure it's not drawing 8 bars?  1 up, 1 down (at the same x-axis point), 2 up, 2 of size 0, and 2 up is 8 bars.

Comment: Have you thought about using a debugger? or at least add some system.out's inside your loop?

Comment: oh, and you are doubling the value of i each time through the loop.

Comment: please insert something like `System.out.println("Created bar "+i+" at "+<horizontal_position>+", "+<vertical position>);` before each `i++` where those positions are the ones from moveHorizontal and moveVertical.  This should help understand if the loop is running correctly.

Comment: run it through a debugger, or print out something inside the loop so you can see where you are.

Comment: This is a debugging issue.

Comment: I now see the outer lines are the axis.  You are doubling i which gives 4 bars.

Comment: you loop executes 4 times, each time producing 2 bars - hence total of 8

Comment: I'm a little rusty with Java, but shouldn't `posX=+5` be `posX+=5`? (that still wouldn't explain the problem)

Comment: I added console output after each bar is created and after each 'pos=+5':

Bar 1 drawn
Bar 2 drawn
'posX =+ 5' exectuted
Bar 3 drawn
Bar 4 drawn
'posX =+ 5' exectuted
Bar 5 drawn
Bar 6 drawn
'posX =+ 5' exectuted
Bar 7 drawn
Bar 8 drawn
'posX =+ 5' exectuted

Loop finished

So it was completing the loop but just not drawing the bars

Answer (score 1):

```
(int i=0,j=0;i<barCount;j++)
```

look at it. J++?
Shouldn't it be:

```
for (int i=0;i<barCount;i++)
```

Comment: He does define in the comment next to the `for()` loop what `j` is for.

Comment: Well, he does increment i twice in the body of the loop. Not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Change `posX=+5` to `posX+=10` (or `posX+=15` depending on how you want it to look). You're code has 2 errors:

1. You are setting posX to 5 each time instead of incrementing it.
2. You are incrementing it by too small of a number. Even with fixing the first error, during the first loop, you draw bars at xPos -15 and -10, then you increment xPos to -10 and draw bars at xPos -10 and -5 (See: you've drawn -10 twice already)

Comment: Yeah, this is it, the compiler is probably interpreting `posX=+5` as `posX=5` which makes sense as it is a "positive 5". That's why it still compiled.

Comment: Nope, I changed it and the 4 bars all clumped together instead of Bar 2 and 3 being spaced apart (seemingly it just ignored it)

Answer (score 0):

No wonder you get a lot of views with no answers. I can't tell, either. Here's a couple of tips.

Put your code in a method instead of making everything static. Try public void run() {} if nothing else. Create an instance in main and invoke run.

Don't update the variables in for loop outside the loop. In a larger loop, that would be confusing.

Try using two for loops instead of the kloogie you have now.

Test the loop logic by removing the graphics code and just doing System.out.println() with meaningful messages.